# how to get number of days from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

how to get number of days between two dates but its not working i think my date format not correct but how to change date format and get number of days

```
$scope.ChangeDate = function () {      
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var firstDate = $scope.Current.PlainnedStart;
    var secondDate = $scope.Current.PlainnedEnd;
    if (!angular.isUndefined(firstDate) && !angular.isUndefined(secondDate)) {
        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
        alert(diffDays);
        $scope.Current.NOD = ++diffDays;          
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km15u.png)

[image]

---

```
<input type="text" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ChangeDate()"
       id="date" ng-model="Current.PlainnedStart"
       class="floating-label mdl-textfield__input" placeholder="">
```

Comment: Just to check, are you getting the string value from those 2 inputs? Or date object?

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/trainerplus/nj64wsb7/

Comment: <input type="text" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ChangeDate()" id="date" ng-model="Current.PlainnedStart"  class="floating-label mdl-textfield__input" placeholder="">

Comment: Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive. The `onchange` attribute is not integrated with the AngularJS framework.  Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert both dates into the JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. From what I can see, the inputs from both date inputs are in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format, and this will cause some problems if you try to directly convert it into the Date object. Instead, you should convert it to 'yyyy-mm-dd' before converting it to a date object.

Then, you can calculate the difference between both dates.

```js
const str1 = '17-04-2019';
const str2 = '20-04-2019';

const toDate = dateStr => {
  const parts = dateStr.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}

const diff =  Math.floor((toDate(str2) - toDate(str1) ) / 86400000); 

console.log(diff)
```

Comment: @AdeelAijaz can you try running console.log() on firstDate or secondDate? Let me know what is the result. I just want to see the format.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="day1" ng-blur="getDate(day1)" type="text" readonly />


$scope.getDate= function (date) {
var dates = new Date();
console.log(dates);
}
```

you can easily manage with momentjs with date evens

```
var a = moment('2018-04-17T07:00:00.000Z');
var b = moment('2018-04-27T07:00:00.000Z'); 
var days = b.diff(a, 'days');
```

http://momentjs.com/

or with Javascript

```
var a = new Date("2018-04-17T07:00:00.000Z"); 
var b = new Date("2018-04-27T07:00:00.000Z");
var dayDif = (a - b)  / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer above you can either split the string to get the values. Or change it like below

Ex:Suppose my date string is

```
var str1 = '17-Apr-2019';
var str2 = '20-Apr-2019';

var diff = Math.abs(new Date(str2).getDate() - new Date(str1).getDate()); 
console.log(diff)

Output => 3
```

Or **if you dont want any code changes**.
Change the format of the datepicker to (mm-dd-yyyy) you will get same output